# How to switch among multiple tables (documents) in angularjs and mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongoose

My goal is to have mongoDB with multiple tables (collections of documents), each per some user. So how can I "switch" among multiple tables at runtime (particular table is known after particular user is logged in)?
I have this code snipped...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TicketSchema = new Schema({
  Unit_descriptor: String,
     ...
  Total_tons: Number
}, { strict: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model('tickets_user1', TicketSchema);
```

...and I want to be able to switch table for currently logged user, for example: tables could have suffix with username as in code above.

I tried to create exported function called later from controller and swap table, like this:

```
var auth = require('../../auth/auth.service.js');
...
module.exports.initTable = function initTable() {
    module.exports = mongoose.model('tickets_user2', TicketSchema);
};
```

...which does not swap tables, user1's data are still in place.

So, how could I achieve this? THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating the second model like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TicketSchema = new Schema({
  Unit_descriptor: String,
  ...
  Total_tons: Number
}, { strict: false });

var table = '';

function reloadForUser(user){
  var userTable = user.table;
  if(userTable != undefined) {
    table = userTable;
  }
  return mongoose.model(table, TicketSchema, table);
}

exports.reloadForUser = reloadForUser;
```

and then when I need it I just require it and call defined function:

```
Ticket = require('./reload.model');
Ticket = Ticket.reloadForUser(username);
```